# search records through repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, repeater

I try to search records in asp.net for this first I create stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spsearchdocuments]
   @Name nvarchar(50)  
as   
   SELECT     
      dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
      dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
      dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,
      dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate,
      dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
      dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
      dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
      dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
   FROM         
      dbo.DocumentInfo 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
   WHERE
      [DocName] like @Name+'%'
```

and then when I call this procedure in a function like this

```
public DataTable searchdcouments(string Name )
{
    return db.ExecuteDataSet("spsearchdocuments", new object[] { Name }).Tables[0];
}
```

and when I call this function in .aspx form behind search button like this

```
protected void Btn_submits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    Repeater4.DataSource = sear.searchdcouments(searz.Text);
    Repeater4.DataBind();           
}
```

and when I debug my project and write keyword then it not show me any record where record exist in database

Have a look below pictures

When I enter keyword

[image: keyword]

and when I click on search button it shows me like this

[image: show no records.]

Comment: I would check searz.Text to make sure it doesn't have trailing space.

Comment: plz check this <div>
          <asp:TextBox ID="searz" runat="server"  class="searches" type="text" CausesValidation="false"  placeholder="Search Documents"></asp:TextBox>
   <button id="submits" class="submit" runat="server"  type="submit"  onserverclick="Btn_submits_Click" CausesValidation="false" value="Search" validationgroup="123">Search</button>
  
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mistyping your keyword. It's "ERP SYSTEM" in DB, and "erpssystem" in the search box

**Edit after your comment**

"like google" means that you have to run your select every time search string changes, e.g. user types/deletes a letter.

To do this take your *searz* object and add a handler to it's "value changed" event.

**second edit**

Assuming it is a TextBox and you are using VisualStudio, open *searz*'s properties and find `TextChanged` event. Double-clicking it will create TextChanged event handler, that you'd fill in like so:

```
protected void searz_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater4.DataSource = sear.searchdcouments(searz.Text);
    Repeater4.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i like to search like google when we enter just 's' or any other word more records shown and display in page ..same as i do when i enter same like as keyword then more records will be shown for e.g when i enter erp then if more that 1 records exist in database then all records should be displayed

Comment: Updated my answer after your comment

Comment: when i do this it shows me error...  protected void Btn_submits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searz.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(TextChanged);
            
        }
        private void TextChanged(object Sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Repeater4.DataSource = sear.searchdcouments(searz.Text);
            Repeater4.DataBind();
        }

Comment: ERROR: The type or namespace name 'TextChangedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)